# Error: Unresolved reference 'selenium' What is the reason?

Tags: python, selenium

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from selenium import selenium
import unittest, time, re

class rc(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        self.verificationErrors = []
        self.selenium = selenium("localhost", 4444, "*chrome", "http://stackoverflow.com/")
        self.selenium.start()

    def test_rc(self):
        sel = self.selenium
        sel.open("/")
        sel.type("id=kw", "selenium")
        sel.click("id=container")
        sel.click("id=su")

    def tearDown(self):
        self.selenium.stop()
        self.assertEqual([], self.verificationErrors)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

This is recorded with selenium IDE, into selenium remote control code. In the IDE test is passed.

But in pycharm open, the first line (`from selenium import selenium`)

There will be an error: `Unresolved reference 'selenium'`

What is the reason?

My environment is

- python3.5
- selenium3.3.1
- selenium-server-standalone-3.3.1.jar

Comment: Can you post the actual, unedited, complete, error message?

Comment: If you cannot import a module, it's likely your `sys.path` is off. Do `import selenium; print selenium` in your Selenium IDE and note the path. Then `import sys; print sys.path` in PyCharm and see what's missing. Update your project / module settings to include the missing directories.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but How to do this? “Do import selenium; print selenium in your Selenium IDE and note the path”。。

Comment: 。I was just learning to use selenium server
Did not find how to print the path in selenkum server

Comment: I just write the code to pycharm will be prompted to error,